# Filter stock moves and return order's

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to filter in Tree view SO's that have stock.pickings and some stock.moves in those pickings are in a state "assigned".

I created selection field that is computed and fnct_search  method but it's not even triggered. what is wrong in my code? and logic.

```py
picking_id_states = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'), ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
        ('waiting', 'Waiting Another Operation'),
        ('confirmed', 'Waiting Availability'),
        ('partially_available', 'Partially Available'),
        ('assigned', 'Available'), ('done', 'Done')], compute='compute_picking_state', string='Picking State',
        fnct_search='_move_search', store=False, copy=False, index=True, readonly=True)

def _move_search(self, operator, value):
    print "test"
    for so in self:
        moves = so.picking_ids.mapped('move_lines')
        filtered_moves = moves.filtered(lambda l: l.state == 'assigned')
        if filtered_moves:
            so_ids = filtered_moves.mapped('picking_id.sale_id')
            return [('id', 'in', so_ids)]

@api.depends('order_line.move_ids', 'order_line.move_ids.state')
    def compute_picking_state(self):
        for order in self:
            for picking in order.picking_ids:
                order.picking_id_state = picking.state
```

XML code is

```xml
<record id="view_sale_order_search_picking_state" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Config Hetlta picking state</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="user_id" position="after">
                <field name="picking_id_state"/>
                <field name="note"/>
            </field>
            <filter name="sales" position="after">
                <filter string="Picking state" name="picking_id_states" />
            </filter>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `self` in computed fields search methods is always empty, there are no recordsets. You have to take the operator and value (search term) and create your own "indirect" search for order ids.

But a maybe easier way is to just store the computed field. Odoo can only search by database persistent fields, which would be given when stored.